# Email delivery error: "554 - 5.2.1 Too many failures for the recipient." Need help resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Tags: javascript, smtp, zoho

It's a simple nodejs script that mails contact forms using Zoho mail SMTP. I also double checked SPF assign values it's seems good

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its recipients. This is a permanent error.

suman.chaudhary3600@gmail.com, ERROR CODE :554 - 5.2.1 Too many failures for the recipient



Reporting-MTA: dns; mx.zohomail.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 19 Jul 2023 05:21:56 +0000

Original-Recipient: rfc822; suman.chaudhary3600@gmail.com
Final-Recipient: rfc822; suman.chaudhary3600@gmail.com
Status: 554
Action: failed
Last-Attempt-Date: 19 Jul 2023 05:22:01 GMT
Diagnostic-Code: 5.2.1 Too many failures for the recipient


Received:from [169.254.10.181] (ec2-18-141-146-94.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [18.141.146.94]) by mx.zohomail.com
    with SMTPS id 1689744118693412.08009180878537; Tue, 18 Jul 2023 22:21:58 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID:<c478140c-2fae-556c-9f66-b4310f0dccc3@gmail.com>
Date:Wed, 19 Jul 2023 05:21:56 +0000
From:suman.chaudhary3600@gmail.com
To:suman.chaudhary3600@gmail.com
Subject:New Contact Form Submission
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Here is the implementation of the API [`Implementation`](https://www.sumanmukhiya.com.np/#/contact) and here is the source code [Source Code](https://github.com/CyborgMKH/mailer) and here is the deployment [Deployment](https://ill-blue-caterpillar-cuff.cyclic.app/)

It was working correctly yesterday and I checked today and tried to send mail suddenly I am not able to receive the mail today as expected from contact-form from the implementation

Comment: Posts must be self-contained. You can include reference links but the details must be in the question. Read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am assuming the recipient is correct and your mail passes SPAM tests. Note: the `To` and `From` are the same. The sender must be from a domain you registered with Zoho. It might be that Gmail is blocking Zoho from sending emails using a Gmail `From` address using a host that is not part of Gmail.